# All except one directory in mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have little problem with mod_rewrite and I absolutely have no idea what to do with this.

I have this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w/]*)$ index.php/?page=$1 [L]
```

This rule works for every directory. I want this rule to work but except one directory - "test".
What I need to change in this rule?

For example:
I want this URLS redirecting to index.php/?page=$1:
http://test.com/account
http://test.com/dog
http://test.com/cat
And I want only this URL not redirecting to index.php/?page=$1:
http://test.com/test (only test)

Thanx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this **RewriteCond** line just before your rewrite rule, so it looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test(/|$)
RewriteRule ^([\w/]*)$ index.php/?page=$1 [L]
```

If (for some *strange* reason) it does not work -- please provide an example of working URL (the one that needs to be redirected) and the one that should not.