# .htaccess interfering with $_SESSION

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a forum script I've written, and I have an installer too. The forum script works by rewriting all the URLs to `index.php` (it's an MVC setup) and then `PHP` routes the various requests to where they need to go. The problem is that although the installer also uses an `install/index.php` in a very similar way via `MVC`, the `SESSION` variable isn't updating here for some reason which I need to do the install. I've narrowed it down to line #9 below in my `.htaccess` file. If I leave it commented, then my forum works, but the installer doesn't.

If I uncomment it, my installer works, but URL rewriting on the forum doesn't work. I think I now know why this is but I have no idea how to fix it. I believe it's because the `htaccess` is rewriting everything to `index.php`, including `install/index.php` so I need to have some way of missing out the install folder of the `htaccess` rules on lines #11, #12 & #13.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
RewriteEngine On

# UNCOMMENT AND PROPERLY SET THE RewriteBase IF THE REWRITE RULES ARE NOT WORKING PROPERLY.
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: which one is line 9? Mark  it. `.htaccess` does not interfere with `$_SESSION`. You will have another issue that is causing this side effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All except one directory in mod\_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942652/all-except-one-directory-in-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.htaccess` does not interfere with `$_SESSION`.

If your issue *is* centred around your `install/` folder, then you need to write a more careful `.htaccess` mod_rewrite, to accept (ie ignore) the required accesses to `install/` folder:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Check and ignore if the requested path is /install/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/install(/|$)  
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

[See here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942652/all-except-one-directory-in-mod-rewrite)